# Large vocabulary speech recognition in sphinx4

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

As far as I know till now, sphinx4 requires grammar to identify the words. Is there anyway to get the input without using grammar rules, that is not in the grammar, somewhat like I am dictating and it will write what I will say?

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know till now, sphinx4 requires grammar to identify the words.

No, sphinx4 supports large vocabulary speech recognition

> Is there anyway to get the input without using grammar rules, that is not in the grammar, somewhat like I am dictating and it will write what I will say? Or any algorithm maybe to check it?

You need to update sphinx4-5prealpha version.

You can check [transcriber demo](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/transcriber/TranscriberDemo.java) for example of large vocabulary speech recognition setup.

The code should look like this:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;

public class TranscriberDemo {       

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration
                .setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration
                .setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        configuration
                .setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");

        LiveSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new LiveSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
        recognizer.startRecognition(true);

        SpeechResult result;
        while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
            System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());
        }
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
    }
}
```